# Form alignment collapses into single row

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-grid

I have the parent element set to `newTableForm` with `labelColumn` and `mainFormColumn` as children - but with the current CSS everything collapses into one row:

```css
.newTableForm {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: 30px 30px 30px 40px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "... main" "labels main" "labels main" "... main";
  border: 2px dashed deeppink;
}

.labelColumn {
  grid-area: labels;
}

.mainFormColumn {
  grid-area: main;
}
```

```html
<form method='post' action="/admin-post.php" class="newTableForm">
  <h4 class="mainFormColumn">
    Add a new price compare table
  </h4>
  <label for="store" class="labelColumn">Store</label>
  <input type="text" name="store" placeholder="" class="mainFormColumn"/>
  <label for="product-page" class="labelColumn">Product Page Link</label>
  <input type="text" name="product-page" placeholder="Copy address here" class="mainFormColumn" />
  <button class="mainFormColumn">Save new price compare table</button>
</form>
```

Is there a way to undo the single column stacking behavior here? I would remove the template areas altogether if not for the blank sections with ... (above and below the label section)

Comment: also remove grid-area from `.labelColumn & .mainFormColumn` and what type of lay-out you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again you can drop `grid-template-areas` as *multiple grid-areas overlap* - and you can use *pseudo elements* for this:

- place `labelColumn` into the *first column* using `grid-column: 1` and `mainFormColumn` into the *second column* using `grid-column: 2`.
- `after` element will be the *first column* in the *last row* using `grid-row: -2` and `grid-column: 1`
- `before` will be *first column* in the *first row* using `grid-column: 1`

See demo below:

```css
.newTableForm {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: 30px 30px 30px 40px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  border: 2px dashed deeppink;
}

.labelColumn {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.mainFormColumn {
  grid-column: 2;
}
.newTableForm:after, .newTableForm:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.newTableForm:after {
  grid-row: -2;
}
```

```html
<form method='post' action="/admin-post.php" class="newTableForm">
  <h4 class="mainFormColumn">
    Add a new price compare table
  </h4>
  <label for="store" class="labelColumn">Store</label>
  <input type="text" name="store" placeholder="" class="mainFormColumn"/>
  <label for="product-page" class="labelColumn">Product Page Link</label>
  <input type="text" name="product-page" placeholder="Copy address here" class="mainFormColumn" />

  <button class="mainFormColumn">Save new price compare table</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just update your `.newTableForm` css with some updates. I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```
.newTableForm {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px dashed deeppink;
}
```

Comment: Hi, the stacking problem is gone with this code. But I wanted a left column of labels, this doesn't do that.