# Dynamic rows using CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-grid

I'm using Grid to present some data. I would like to have a layout where the first row is headers, the second row is sub-headers and the third is the main content. This is quite simple to achieve using the `grid-template-areas` property for the `grid-container`. My problem is that i'd like the first row to be generated only once whereas the second and third rows should be dynamic.

I am stuck trying to get the first two rows right so I will only refer to those two in my example.

I have my CSS `grid container` defined as follows:

```
.grid-container {
      display:grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
      grid-template-rows: auto;
      grid-template-areas:
         "header1 header2 header3"
         "subheader1 . subheader2";
}

.header-item-1 {
     grid-area: header1;
}

.header-item-2 {
     grid-area: header2;
}

.header-item-3 {
     grid-area: header3;
}

.sub-header-item-1 {
     grid-area: subheader1;
}

.sub-header-item-2 {
     grid-area: subheader2;
}
```

My html is as follows:

```
<ul class="grid-container">
    <li class="header-item-1">header1</li>
    <li class="header-item-2">header2</li>
    <li class="header-item-3">header3</li>

<!-- ko foreach: { data: subheaderItem, as: 'subheader' } -->

    <li class="sub-header-item-1" data-bind="text: subheader.name"></li>
    <li class="sub-header-item-2" data-bind="text: subheader.type></li>

<!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

What this produces is a layout where the first row is correct, the second row has the correct layout but all iterations of the sub-headers are placed in the same cells like:

```
 *        *       *
***              ***
```

What i'm after is:

```
 *        *       *
 *                *
 *                *
 *                *
....
```

Would appreciate any tips on how to get this done ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove `grid-template-areas` (same *grid areas* will overlap - see another [`example here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55325488/form-alignment-collapses-into-single-row)) and use a 3-column layout using `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)` and then setting `grid-column: 1` for `sub-header-item-1` and `grid-column: 3` for `sub-header-item-2`.

See demo below:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

.sub-header-item-1 {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.sub-header-item-2 {
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid-container">
  <li class="header-item-1">header1</li>
  <li class="header-item-2">header2</li>
  <li class="header-item-3">header3</li>
  <li class="sub-header-item-1">1</li>
  <li class="sub-header-item-2">3</li>
  <li class="sub-header-item-1">1</li>
  <li class="sub-header-item-2">3</li>
  <li class="sub-header-item-1">1</li>
  <li class="sub-header-item-2">3</li>
</ul>
```